# How to extract Volume and ParentDir from an PUNICODESTRING in mini filter driver?

Tags: driver, windows-kernel, minifilter

I am writing a mini-filter driver for windows. I can get the process image name by my `GetProcessFileName` function that use `ZwQueryInformationProcess` to get process image file name and returns a PUNICODESTRING with a value like this:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Common Files\ACD Systems\PicaView\ACDSeePicaView.exe
```

but I want to extract Volume and ParentDir from this PUNICODESTRING in three variables. For example

```
PUNICODESTRING volume;
PUNICODESTRING parentdir;
PUNICODESTRING processname;
```

how can do this , so my variables will be:

```
volume  ---> \Device\HarddiskVolume2\
parentdir ---> Program Files\Common Files\ACD Systems\PicaView\
processname ---> ACDSeePicaView.exe
```

Comment: This is to implement string parsing or string splitting logic. simply a matter of truncating from the front and back from the '\' delimiter. strtok makes it easy, but it's better not to use it in the kernel.

Comment: you are right.have any idea to extract current process path in kernel mode driver in windows?

Comment: If you agree with my opinion, you can solve it simply. parentdir starts at the third '\' from the beginning. processname takes a string from the end of the string up to the first '\'. Simply think.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FltParseFileName` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltparsefilename

> FltParseFileName parses the extension, stream, and final component
> from a file name string.

```
NTSTATUS FLTAPI FltParseFileName(
  [in]      PCUNICODE_STRING FileName,
  [in, out] PUNICODE_STRING  Extension,
  [in, out] PUNICODE_STRING  Stream,
  [in, out] PUNICODE_STRING  FinalComponent
);
```

The function takes a UNICODE_STRING structure pointer and returns the file extension, stream, and final component.

**\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Common Files\ACD Systems\PicaView\ACDSeePicaView.exe**

*Extension*: "exe"

*FinalComponent*: "ACDSeePicaView"

You can get the volume name by the getting string before the third backslash, and the parent directory by subtracting the volume and final component + extension from the string.

Here is a function to extract the volume name from a file path string

```
NTSTATUS GetVolumeNameFromFileName(PUNICODE_STRING FileName, PUNICODE_STRING VolumeName) {

NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

PWCHAR fileName = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_PAGED, FileName->Length + sizeof(WCHAR), 100);

if (fileName == NULL) {
    KdPrint(("GetVolumeNameFromFileName -> Not enough memory to allocate for the file name.\r\n"));
    return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}

RtlCopyMemory(fileName, FileName->Buffer, FileName->Length);

WCHAR* p;

//Search the third backslash in the file name string

int pos = 0;
int slashIndex = -1;

p = wcschr(fileName, L'\\');

while (p != NULL && pos < 3) {

    if (pos == 2) {
        slashIndex = p - fileName;
    }
    else {
        p = wcschr(p + 1, L'\\');
    }

    pos += 1;

}

ExFreePoolWithTag(fileName, 100);

if (slashIndex == -1) {
    KdPrint(("GetVolumeNameFromFileName -> Failed to get the directory separator index.\r\n"));
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

UNICODE_STRING volumeName = { 0 };

volumeName.Length = 0;
volumeName.MaximumLength = (slashIndex + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
volumeName.Buffer = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_PAGED, volumeName.MaximumLength, 101);

status = RtlUnicodeStringCchCopyN(&volumeName, FileName, slashIndex);

if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    *VolumeName = volumeName;
}
else {
    KdPrint(("GetVolumeNameFromFileName -> RtlUnicodeStringCchCopyN function failed (%08x).\r\n", status));
}

return status;
```

}